AWS Lambda OpenSearch Serverless Connection Issues
I am working on an AWS Lambda function written in Python to interact with an OpenSearch Serverless collection. The Lambda function is deployed in a VPC, and the OpenSearch Serverless endpoint is also within the same VPC. Despite ensuring that all permissions and VPC configurations are correct, I keep encountering a 404 error when trying to list collections or connect to the OpenSearch collection. Below are the details of my setup and the code snippets used.
Lambda Function Code:
import json
import boto3
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def create_opensearch_client():
    try:
        session = boto3.Session()
        client = session.client('opensearchserverless', 
                                endpoint_url="https://zz44ttfldnkz06666uul.us-east-1.aoss.amazonaws.com",
                                verify=False,
                                use_ssl=True)
        logger.info("OpenSearch client created successfully")
        return client
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error creating OpenSearch client: {str(e)}")
        logger.error(f"Traceback: {traceback.format_exc()}")
        raise

def test_opensearch_connection(client):
    try:
        response = client.list_collections()
        logger.info(f"Successfully listed collections: {json.dumps(response, default=str)}")
        
        response = client.batch_get_collection(ids=['my-collection-id'])
        logger.info(f"Successfully got collection details: {json.dumps(response, default=str)}")
        
        return True
    except ClientError as e:
        logger.error(f"Error connecting to OpenSearch: {str(e)}")
        return False

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info("Lambda function started")
    client = create_opensearch_client()
    connection_successful = test_opensearch_connection(client)
    
    if connection_successful:
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'Successfully connected to OpenSearch collection.'
        }
    else:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': 'Failed to connect to OpenSearch collection.'
        }

Error Message:
"Error in OpenSearch connection test: An error occurred (404) when calling the ListCollections operation"

Verification Steps:

Verified the OpenSearch endpoint and collection using AWS CLI:
aws opensearchserverless list-collections
aws opensearchserverless batch-get-collection --ids "my-collection-id"


Ensured the Lambda role has the necessary permissions:

aoss:APIAccessAll
es:ESHttpGet, es:ESHttpPost, es:ESHttpPut, es:ESHttpDelete


Double-checked that the Lambda function and OpenSearch endpoint are within the same VPC and subnets.


IAM Policy Attached to Lambda:
Policies:
  - AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
  - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
  - AmazonElasticFileSystemClientReadWriteAccess
  - SecretsManagerReadWrite
  - AmazonRDSFullAccess
  - AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
  - Version: '2012-10-17'
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 'aoss:APIAccessAll'
        Resource: 'arn:aws:aoss:us-east-1:123456789012:collection/my-collection-id'
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 'lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration'
        Resource: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:my-lambda-function'
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 'es:ESHttpGet'
          - 'es:ESHttpPost'
          - 'es:ESHttpPut'
          - 'es:ESHttpDelete'
        Resource: 'arn:aws:aoss:us-east-1:123456789012:collection/my-collection-id/*'

VPC Configuration:

The Lambda function is associated with the correct subnets and security groups.
The subnets and security groups have been verified multiple times for correctness.

Problem:
Despite following the above steps, the Lambda function fails with a 404 error when trying to interact with the OpenSearch Serverless collection. What could be the possible reasons for this issue, and how can I resolve it?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

I may be missing something silly, but where are you using your host parameter when creating the client?

I use endpoint_url
